# which .NET framework does VS developer server run?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, development-environment

When a site is running in IIS it is possible to choose .NET version in application pool settings.

How do I know which version of .NET is developer server running when I start my site from Visual Studio(2010)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use the .NET framework version selected in Target Framework under project properties.

You can verify this by double-clicking on the ASP.NET Development Server task bar icon and inspecting the ASP.NET version.